# '/usr/bin/kvm-spice': No such file or directory when starting virt-viewer

Tags: apt, package-management, packaging

When I start a VM inside virt-manager (virt-viewer) I get this error:

```
'/usr/bin/kvm-spice': No such file or directory
```

how should I install kvm-spice? It was there before, somehow it is gone

Answer (score 3):

It's a symlink to /usr/bin/kvm:

```
file /usr/bin/kvm-spice
/usr/bin/kvm-spice: symbolic link to kvm
```

Can just recreate it:
`ln -s kvm /usr/bin/kvm-spice`
It's part of qemu-kvm:

```
dpkg-query -S /usr/bin/kvm-spice
qemu-kvm: /usr/bin/kvm-spice
```

So you can also try reinstalling this package:
`apt-get install --reinstall qemu-kvm`